# pytesseract does not work in windows platform

Tags: python, windows, ocr, python-tesseract

I am giving the code below, which works perfect in linux platform, but fails to execute in winodws platform. It has to do with pytesseract behaviour.

```
def imgps():
try:
    answer = filedialog.askdirectory(parent=root,
                                     initialdir=os.getcwd(), title="Please select a folder:")
    for fn in os.listdir(answer):
        if fn.endswith(".png") or fn.endswith(".jpg"):
            x = os.path.join(answer, fn)
            print(x) #loop breaks after this.
            rd = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(x), lang='eng').replace('-\n', '') \
                .replace('\n', ' ').encode("ascii", 'ignore')
            tb9.insert('insert', rd)
            tb9.insert('insert', br)
        else:
            continue
except:
    messagebox.showinfo(message="No File to Display.")
```

There is a button click to execute above function. I think I don't have to give its code too. Help would be appreciated. What I have seen that print command executes for first file and then loop breaks, which confirms that problem is with pytesseract behaviour in windows. Help shall be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I had to find a solution myself. There is a code line like this.
`pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:/Program Files/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe'` which needs to be added in the function to tell pytesseract the location for using tesseract. Setting environment variables can work only if the script and the tesseract program files are on the same drive. If they are on different drive then this is the work around.